# Set Up OL3 with Closure

Tags: javascript, openlayers, google-closure, openlayers-3

Does anybody have a site or a tutorial of how to set up Openlayers 3 with Closure?
I tried it now for a few days and still have to give up.

You need the Closure Library to set up the Open Layers Library.

But how do I combine this? At the moment I use the built ol.js by OpenLayers which does its deed, but in the future this may not be the right thing.

It seems to be important where each script is placed, but since I am using this on a huge website, with Java + Spring, IBATIS, postgreSQL and JAWR, it is rather complex to implement Closure and Openlayers into this, without just using one or two Javascript libraries.

Comment: I'm also finding numerous issues trying to use a goog.ui.Menu within an OL3 application.  The ol-debug.js file is destroying the goog namespace and subsequent goog.require calls fail.

Answer (score 1):

You must link the ol-deps.js and goog/base.js in your HTML